# Does Ajax automatically refresh the DOM after Jquery sends post?

Tags: jquery, ajax

I just started to work with Ajax and I'm not totally lost... not sure how does it really works.

I thought Ajax sends (by example a post) to the server and returns x data but that data is automatically added to the DOM (without reloading the page). I have the following jquery ajax script:

```
$.ajax({
    method: "POST",
    url: "/url",
    data: { 
        'varname': varname, 
        'varname2': varname2
        // etc
    }
});

return false;
```

I just learned (but somehow I already was expecting this...) that what it returns is inside data and it's not synced with the browser (current) DOM or html. I did an alert(data) and saw the whole new html compiled code:

```
}).done(function(data) {
    alert(data);
});

return false;
```

The question is: how am I supposed to add what I need from data to the current html. I mean if the variables sent triggers a new script (and new content is generated) how do I put the new content, refreshing or updating the old one?

Comment: this depends on your html structure and structure of ajax received data, you'll have to read and interpret the data and then insert it via jQuery or javascript into the desired site-elements

Comment: Look at `$.load` to "automatically update the DOM" for you, without having to process the result yourself:  http://api.jquery.com/load/

Comment: So I just replace it with `$( "#div" ).load( "/url" );`? Where do I specify the variables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was very simple: Take what I need and print it:

```
    }).done(function(data) {
        var new_content = $(data).find('#search');
        $('#search').html(new_content);
    });
```

Thanks for your answers.

Answer (score 3):

Ajax is just a term given to the process of making an HTTP request, from JavaScript, without loading a new page.

> I just learned (but somehow I already was expecting this...) that what it returns is inside data and it's not synced with the browser (current) DOM or html.

Correct. The data is made available to JavaScript so that your code can do whatever you like with it.

> The question is: how am I supposed to add what I need from data to the current html.

DOM Manipulation.

jQuery provides many methods to help with that, including [`replaceWith`](http://api.jquery.com/replacewith/) and [`append`](http://api.jquery.com/append/).

Comment: Hey thanks for your answer, I'm looking here how to make it work. I was able to improve and simplify my php script but about ajax I can only think of something like `$( "html" ).html( data );` that it's actually "working", but it breaks the header and footer javascripts (all js in fact, don't know why). I just need to take a div container from `data` but I don't know how. Can you help me?

Comment: @ChazyChaz — You should fetch *just* the data you want to replace from the server, and then replace just that, not the entire document. Otherwise you might as well not use Ajax.

Comment: Ok I just found `filter` and `find`. I'm going to try.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using .done
You may edit your code to

```
$.ajax({
method: "POST",
url: "/url",
data: JSON.stringify({ 
    'varname': varname, 
    'varname2': varname2
    //etc
}),
dataType: "json",
contentType : "application/json;charset=utf-8", // so that your ajax call will automatically convert the data returned from the server as json.
success: function(response){
    // do your job here. You may change DOMs, manipulate data to client.
 }
});
```

using the code above, you can get the data returned from the server without a hitch.

Comment: This is the old way of using `.done` (ie `.done` is the newer way of using `.success`).  Otherwise they are identical.   How does this answer the question?

Answer (score 0):

No, your script must handle the response from the server and decide what to do with it.

If you wish to insert html returned from your ajax request and insert it intto the DOM/page then you could look into functions such as [html](http://api.jquery.com/html/), [append](http://api.jquery.com/append/) and [insertAfter](http://api.jquery.com/insertAfter/) to accomplish this.

An example might look like this:

```
}).done(function(data) {
    $('#someContainerId').html(data);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you have to setup the requested page (url) to respond with only the data you need (e.g. you may not need entire webpage between `<html>` and `</html>`.

At the start of the PHP file use

```
if(!empty($_POST['PASSED_VARIABLE'])) {
    ...
    // Manipulate the data.
    ...

    echo $data; // Echo the result.
}
```

When your Ajax function is done, you can insert the received data into DOM:

```
.done(function(data) {
    $('div#results').html(data); // Or any other DOM manipulation.
})
```

Comment: Does adding `$('div#results').html(data);` will update the page with the new content? Why do I need the php code?

Comment: Can you define what are you expecting to achieve? Do you want to change just a part of your page or your page completely?

Comment: I want to send some variables to trigger an script and generate content, then I need to print it without reloading the page.